# ¿Podrían ayudarme con este código?

Tags: java, arraylist

Necesito crear un programa en Java que permita guardar la información personal de varias personas, y luego generar un método que reporte la cantidad de personas que están registrados y otro método donde imprima los datos de todas las personas que se registraron en el sistema. Hasta el momento esto es lo que hice, apenas estoy empezando a programar y no se si esté bien, espero puedan ayudarme.

Este es mi código:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class datos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int DNI;
        int edad;
        String nombre;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre: ");
        nombre=entrada.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Ingrese su edad: "); 
    edad=entrada.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Ingrese su número de DNI: ");
    DNI=entrada.nextInt();

    ArrayList <Persona> listaPersonas= new ArrayList<Persona>();

    listaPersonas.add(new Persona(DNI, edad, nombre));

    for(Persona e: listaPersonas){

        System.out.println(e.dameDatos());
    }

  }

}

class Persona { 
    public Persona(String nombre, int edad, int DNI){   
}

Persona(int DNI, int edad, String nombre) {

    this.nombre=nombre;
    this.edad=edad;
    this.DNI=DNI;
}

public String dameDatos(){

return "La persona se llama "+ nombre +". Tiene "+ edad+" años"+ ". Con número de DNI " + DNI;
}

private String nombre;
private int DNI;
private int edad;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Ademas lee: **[¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)** ¿qué problemas tienes con este código?

Comment: Entonces... ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Haz un metodo de registro que agarre los inputs y vaya creando personas. 
Estas personas puedes guardarlas en algun tipo almacen de colection de java (en este caso puede ser arraylist).
Y basicamente hacer un método de recorrido simple de esa arraylist para mostrar cada persona.

Answer (score 1):

Hola hice unas modificaciones en tu codigo y lo ordene un poco , te felicito esta bastante bueno, sigue asi :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class datos {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ArrayList<Persona> listaPersonas = new ArrayList<Persona>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
    boolean ingresarOtraPersona = true;
    while(ingresarOtraPersona)
    {
        int DNI;
        int edad;
        String nombre;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre: ");
        nombre = entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Ingrese su edad: ");
        edad = entrada.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Ingrese su número de DNI: ");
        DNI = entrada.nextInt();

        listaPersonas.add(new Persona(DNI, edad, nombre));

        System.out.println("¿Desea ingresar otra persona? (s/n)");
        ingresarOtraPersona = sc.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("s");
    }
    System.out.println("La cantidad de personas ingresadas es de : "+listaPersonas.size());
    listaPersonas(listaPersonas);
}

public static void listaPersonas(ArrayList<Persona>listaPersonas)
{
    for (Persona e : listaPersonas)
    {
        System.out.println(e.dameDatos());
    }

    //utilizando lambdas gracias a Java 8
 //     listaPersonas.forEach(System.out::println);
}
}

class Persona 
 {
    private String nombre;
    private int DNI;
    private int edad;

public Persona(String nombre, int edad, int DNI) 
{
}

Persona(int DNI, int edad, String nombre) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.DNI = DNI;
}

public String dameDatos() {

    return "La persona se llama " + nombre + ". Tiene " + edad + " años"
            + ". Con número de DNI " + DNI;
}

//Cuando escribes un System.out.print() y le pasas un objeto el compilador llama directamente al meto toString ,
//Si no lo sobreescribe se llama al metodo de la clase Object
public String toString() {

    return "La persona se llama " + nombre + ". Tiene " + edad + " años"
            + ". Con número de DNI " + DNI;
}
}
```

Comment: Ok, gracias, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que ahí se ve, eso que llevas cumple con lo que pides, excepto obtener el número de  personas que se está registrando, para eso basta con `listaPersonas.size()` y te devolvera en entero el número de persona que hay en la lista `System.out.println("la cantidad de personas es de" + listaPersonas.size());`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.